# which files are need to create .ipa for my application which is done in xcode

Tags: iphone

I am creating a simple application in xcode

Now i need to create ipa for that file.

By google i found some info regarding this.

create a folder named Payload and copy the app file,Zip the fine and rename zip to .ipa.

But i have a doubt in the this path users/username/library/application support/iphone simulator/4.1/Applications

i found a folder named with random alphabets and numbers.

In that i found documents,library,tmp folders along with my application.app.

is i need to copy all the 3 folders into payload or just my application.app is enough.

And i did n't get my icon in over the .ipa.

How can i get it.

can any one pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to **Build and Archive** in Xcode, it will package your app into an .ipa for you.

When in Organizer, click on your app, then click on the `Share...` button, then choose `Save to Disk...`
[image]

Also, I wouldnt suggest manually creating your `.ipa` files.

Comment: In my xcode Build and Archive is not highlighted.I can able to select option why?

Comment: You have to be in Device | Release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using Build and Archive, you can also try dragging and dropping your .app file onto iTunes. Then when you do 'reveal in finder' for the app, you'd see the IPA.