# how do I transfer my iPhone application to my real iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, transfer

I am a registered iOS developer.  How do I get my iPhone application transferred to my personal iPhone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For testing? Just select your device instead of the simulator.

Comment: That's all there is to it. Modern versions of Xcode will automatically download the proper provisioning profiles for you.

Comment: Hi, I get a error Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: There are other things to do if your device is older. You must set architecture targets accordingly. 

XCode4 sets armv7 for iPhone development, but if your device is older, you may need to set armv6. 

This question, not posted by me contain solution to my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/is-it-possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk

Answer (score 4):

You use **Build and Archive** in Xcode to create an ipa file that you can drag into iTunes.  The chosen answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731669/which-files-are-need-to-create-ipa-for-my-application-which-is-done-in-xcode) explains it with a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, I get a error Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Answer (score 1):

Follow Apple's guide here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html

Comment: This is a dead link !

Answer (score 1):

For ios7 and Xcode 5 and for testing it, follow the below steps:

1. You need to request a certificate (if this is your first time)
2. Connect you iPhone to your Mac and then click on "Development in Xcode's Organizer window"
   [image]
3. Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your iOS Developer Program membership and Xcode will automatically generate your certificates.
4. in Xcode, Click on "Product" -->"Destination" --> you should see the name of your iPhone list there so click on it :)
5. in Xcode ,Click "Product" --> "Build for Running" --> "Allow"
6. in Xcode ,Click "Product --> "Run" --> "Allow"

[source](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateLanding.action)

Comment: "You need to request a certificate". How?

Comment: @teewuane take a look at 1. https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/ or 2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979924/how-to-request-ios-development-certificate-in-2013

Answer (score 0):

After you login into iOS Dev Center, you will be able to reach the iOS Provisioning Portal.

There, you will have all procedures and step-by-step guides on how to create your development certificate, register your device, create a mobile provisioning, etc.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action