# How to request iOS Development Certificate in 2013?

Tags: ios, xcode

In the past we create a CSR file with Keychain Access then upload the file via the Apple Dev website. Now with the latest Xcode (4.6.1) it seems we're supposed to be able to request it via Xcode itself. I do not see that option anywhere! There's a "refresh" button in the organizer but it doesn't request the certificate for me even if mine is invalid..

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's not very clear but you need to remove the expired certificate first.

- Click into Certificates/development.
- Click on the expired certificate and revoke it. (This will then allow you to create a new one.)
- Click the plus icon and select iOS App Development.

Comment: Where is Certificates/development? I don't see anything in the organizer tabs or in any of the pull downs for Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove all your expired certs before you can request for a new cert.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your keychain to create the CSR, and then upload it on the new provisioning portal.  Just did it the other day.

Comment: I am having the same issue, there is no way to upload it to the provisioning portal now.  On the "Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles" menu, under the Certificates heading, pressing the "+" (Add) button, on the "What type of certificate do you need? page, the "iOS App Development" option is greyed out and cannot be selected.

Comment: Yeah.. I had the same issue.  I revoked the other certs and the option was then available.  Be careful as this may not be something you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your understanding is correct. I have generated my CSR "by hand", and then I've downloaded the rest via XCode once uploaded on the portal.

I understand the XCode feature is useful for teams, since you have a team Provisioning profile, and a user certificate. It might also be the case for multi-Mac development (like when I'm on my MBA or my iMac, which requires importing the private key from one keychain to the other).

Edit: I'd love to help out more, but when running the "refresh", XCode crashed on me :-)

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: teamId)
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff89ffcaee __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff8b3de3f0 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff8a08b5b7 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x000000010acffd88 +[DTDKTeamBasedService _createRequestDictionaryForTeam:andPlatform:] (in DTDeviceKit)
```

Bizarre that it seems XCode tries to set the TeamId to null :/

Answer (score 0):

My development profile expired while the iOS dev subscription was still valid, so I ran into this same problem. Thanks to you all!

Here is what worked for me, after playing around with the certificates/profiles/etc for a while:

- Removed old expired certs online as described here
- Generated a new development cert request as described here
- I had XCode "Refresh certs" crash multiple times as well.

  - updated XCode from 4.6.1 to 4.6.2 which was just released, still crashed.
- Manually downloaded the "Provisioning Profile/Development" which was listed as "Active (Managed by XCode)" from the dev web site and double-clicked it and only then it was added to XCode OK. It seems you may have to do this manually, the the XCode Refresh button would not do it automatically?
- Finally, to solve a compile (for iOS device) error "The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains", I needed to change the "Project settings-Targets-Code Signing Identity" to my current identity, as described in [Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503). Then the signing was successful.

For other Google searchers benefit, the error message I got was "your team has no current iOS development certificates ... please wait a moment and refresh".

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays iOS App Development option is getting greyed out don't know why.

Even I had this situation and I solved it (made it enabled) using the following steps.

1. Remove the expired development certificates from
   Certificates/Development.
2. Revoke the unused development certificates.
3. Now click on the + button and you are free to select the
4. iOS App Development option.